# Removing all Spaces to format output

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell and have created a text file, which pulls down a list of shares available on a server.

This text file contains numerous white spaces, however I need to remove just the ones in the folder name, for example `Test 2$`.

Ideally I want to just remove this space so that it reads `Test2$`. As I am trying to create a CSV so that it can be used in another script.

I copy the Text file and rename it to csv then copy the contents of that CSV and using the space as a delimiter it then puts the results into columns, however when it does this, it picks up multiple space as well and thus clears all spaces leaving the results as shown below.

is this possible at all?

so I have tried the following:

```
-replace " ",""

$_.trim() -ne
```

both of which remove **all** white spaces. But I only need to remove one.

**My Current code**

```
##############################################################
#Varibles
##############################################################
$PCs = gc "C:\Temp\Servers\Pc.txt"
$FSText = "C:\Temp\Servers\FileShares.txt"
$FSText2 = "C:\Temp\Servers\FileShares2.txt"
$FSERRORS = "C:\Temp\Servers\Errors.txt"
$FSCSV = "C:\Temp\Servers\Server_Shares.csv"
$FSCSV2 = "C:\Temp\Servers\Server_Shares2.csv"
#############################################################

#############################################################
Function Shares{

$PCs|Foreach-Object{ 

Try{
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    $PC = $_
    Get-WmiObject win32_share -ComputerName $_ | Sort-Object -Property path | ft @{Name="Server";Expression={$_.__Server}},path,name

}
  Catch
 { "Unable to obtain to access to shares on $PC " | Out-file $FSERRORS 
   $ErrorActionPreference ='Continue'
}
}
}
#############################################################

Shares | Out-File $FSText

#############################################################
Function Format{
(GC $FSText) -replace "Server", "" -replace "Path","" -replace "Name","" |Set-Content $FSText
(GC $FSText) | ?{$_.trim() -ne ""} |Set-Content $FSText
(GC $FSText) -replace "\s+" , ";"  | Out-File $FSText 


copy-item $FSText $FSText2

Rename-Item $FSText $FSCSV
Rename-Item $FSText2 $FSText
Import-CSV $FSCSV -Delimiter ';' -header Server,Path,Name| Export-CSV $FSCSV2 -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
#############################################################

Format


#############################################################
```

**Results in text file**

```
------    ----            ----   
WKS000001                 IPC$   
WKS000001 C:\             C$     
WKS000001 C:\Temp\Test    Test   
WKS000001 C:\Temp\Test 2$ Test 2$  
WKS000001 C:\WINDOWS      ADMIN$  

------    ----       ----  
WKS000002            IPC$  
WKS000002 C:\        C$    
WKS000002 C:\Windows ADMIN$
```

**Results in csv**

```
Server          Path                Name
------          ----                ----
WKS000001   IPC$    
WKS000001   C:\             C$
WKS000001   C:\Temp\Test        Test
WKS000001   C:\Temp\Test        2$
WKS000001   C:\WINDOWS      ADMIN$
------          ----                ----
WKS000002   IPC$    
WKS000002   C:\             C$
WKS000002   C:\Windows      ADMIN$
```

As you can see it spilts the path of Test 2$ into two columns, however I need it to be in one.

Comment: You're approaching this in the wrong way, it's going to be easier to update the data _before_ you save it to a txt file. Please update your question to include the code you're using to create the txt file so we can see what you're doing :)

Comment: Updated code to reflect what is being asked

Answer (score 2):

You can just update your calculated properties, so the replace is only used by the `Name` Property:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share -ComputerName $PC | 
    Select-Object -Property @{Name="Server";Expression={$_.__Server}},Path,@{Name="Name";Expression={$_.Name.replace(" ","")}} | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Will give you the output:

```
Server    Path            Name
------    ----            ----   
WKS000001                 IPC$   
WKS000001 C:\             C$     
WKS000001 C:\Temp\Test    Test   
WKS000001 C:\Temp\Test 2$ Test2$  
WKS000001 C:\WINDOWS      ADMIN$
```

Comment: thanks, 

however I want to make a csv exactly as it shows, so by setting the delimiter to " " this then assigins each column a result until you hit the space and loses the last columns data for example:

<
Server           Path                     Name
------               ----                       ----   
WKS000001                             IPC$   
WKS000001 C:\                       C$     
WKS000001 C:\Temp\Test      Test   
WKS000001 C:\Temp\Test      2$  
WKS000001 C:\WINDOWS     ADMIN$
>
See how the Test2$ is missing from the third column

Comment: You don't mention anything about dropping a column of data in your question, only about removing spaces from the "folder name"... Can you please update your questions to clearly explain what you actually want. Show example of input data and how you want it to output. Code and/or tabular data in comments doesn't work as it mashes it onto a single line.

Comment: As advised @James C, I have amended my question to full reflect exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using a calculated property in the columns. Use the same way for the Path.

```
Sort-Object -Property path | ft @{Name="Server";Expression={$_.__Server}},@{Name="Path";Expression={$_.Path.replace(" ","")}},Name -autosize
```

But you should be aware that `C:\MyPath` != `C:\My Path`. To use pathes with whitespaces enclose them in `"` or `'`. > `'C:\My Path'`
To replace the path with path in quotes you can use the following code:

```
Sort-Object -Property path | ft @{Name="Server";Expression={$_.__Server}},@{Name="Path";Expression={"'$_.Path'"}},Name -autosize
```

---

Thx James C. for pointing out the use of `.replace()` instead of `.trim()`. I forgot that `.trim()` just works for whitespaces in the beginning and end of a string, while the `.replace()` removes all of the whitespaces.

Comment: Ups I misread that you want to change the column for name not the path. But the way should be the same.

Comment: Thanks T-ME

hjowever the results show as the following;

I would like to preserve the orignal format if possble

'\\WKS0001\root\cimv2:Win32_Share.="IPC$".'

is this possible?

Comment: for me it works: `Get-WmiObject win32_share | Sort-Object -Property path | ft @{Name="Server";Expression={$_.__Server}},@{Name="Path";Expression={$_.Path.replace(" ","")}},@{Name="Name";Expression={$_.Name.replace(" ","")}} -autosize` (this is one line)

Comment: Works after you've swapped `trim()` for `replace()`, mentioning this might help OP realise what you have changed as it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the question is to use the following;

-replace '\s\s+'

This removes all the spaces from the text file and you can replace with a character and delimit on that same character to create your CSV.